# Redirect user back to the original page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, return-path

I have an edit page which is used from different sources. After editing I would like to redirect user to original page. Earlier I used ID (given as a parameter) and Action (hard-coded) to redirect user to certain page, but problems occurs when many different pages can access the same edit page.

Any suggestions how to handle this situation? Should I store complete URL and pass it as a parameter? Are there any known issues with that (string length etc.)?

Comment: In perl CGI this is what referer() is for, to tell you what page linked to the current script. I am not an ASP programmer, but can't ASP tell what page called the edit page?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think there is, but what I was thinking is it A) MVC way of doing it? B) Any problems using this kind of solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use query string parameter "ReturnUrl" as you suggested or Request.UrlReferer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that one. I have to "carry" this url few steps because I am using wizard-like user-interface on this editing page

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this when i i need the referring page.

var referrer = HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer;
        if (referrer != null)
        {
            return Redirect(referrer.ToString());
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");